# Which one is the best way when data preprocessing for right skewed data for clustering?

Tags: k-means, data-preprocessing

Nowadays, I am studying clustering. The question arises when processing data that is highly skewed to the right (like below).

[image]

Generally, known processing methods are log transformation, power transformation(box-cox and yeo-johnson) and so on. When using k-means as a clustering algorithm, I saw the articles that standardization is better than normalization (min-max) because the distance function is Euclidean-based. So, I have tried many ways and I think these three are potent.

- Power transformation(if zero or negative in data then choose yeo-johnson else box-cox)
- Standardization after log transformation
- Power transformation after log transformation (just curious)

Which one is the best way when data preprocessing for right skewed data for clustering?
or, can you suggest a better way?

Comment: Have you tried running it on the raw data, as is? Is the performance not satisfactory?

Comment: When I had tried it on the raw data(not feature engineering), almost all data included in one cluster.

Comment: Log transformation belongs in the power transformation, it is a special case for $\lambda=0$. Log transformation can be used only with positive data (no zeros), to spread it out more evenly. There is no best way to transform your data, it depends on the data. Alternatively, you could choose a different clustering algorithm, which doesn't cluster spheres, which is what k-means does.